# User sees wrong GAL

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a multi-tennant Exchange 2007 environment with one user (at customer 1) who sees the GAL of another customer (customer 2) and not her own GAL.

I checked that the user's msExchUseOAB, msExchQuerySearchBase, and ShowInAddressList attributes are set correctly, and that she is a member of the correct address list (customer 1's). I had a look at the permissions of both GALs (in ADSIEdit) and I do not see how she has permissions to view customer 2's list. Finally, I added a Deny ACE to the GAL of customer 2, for the user, but that didn't help.

Thoughts? What setting am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I fixed this last week when I was looking at msExchUseOAB or msExchQueryBaseDN. I didn't know it, because the other admin I was working with, was seeing his AL when we were testing her account.